# Pandas: check the unique values of a column with datatype 'set'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, set, unique

I have a pandas data frame `my_df`. The column `animals` in `my_df` has the datatype 'set'. Then I tried to use the following code to check how many different values (sets) in this column `animals`:

```
print(my_df.animals.unique())
```

But got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e41c02e0e954> in <module>()

     11 
---> 12 print(my_df.animals.unique())


/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in unique(self)
   1237     @Appender(base._shared_docs['unique'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)
   1238     def unique(self):
-> 1239         result = super(Series, self).unique()
   1240         if is_datetime64tz_dtype(self.dtype):
   1241             # to return array of Timestamp with tz

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py in unique(self)
    971         else:
    972             from pandas.core.nanops import unique1d
--> 973             result = unique1d(values)
    974         return result
    975 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in unique1d(values)
    809     else:
    810         table = _hash.PyObjectHashTable(len(values))
--> 811         uniques = table.unique(_ensure_object(values))
    812     return uniques
    813 

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.unique (pandas/hashtable.c:14383)()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but you can give it a try:

```
In [135]: df
Out[135]:
     animals
0     {1, 2}
1  {1, 2, 3}
2     {1, 2}

In [136]: df.animals.astype(str).unique()
Out[136]: array(['{1, 2}', '{1, 2, 3}'], dtype=object)
```